# Alternative for Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess()

Tags: session, messages, core-session

Due to some reason we disabled the core session on certain modules.

In some files we have the following code

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess()
```

which is not working. can any one please provide an alternative for this?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by `Due to some reason we disabled the core session on certain modules`?

Comment: Fix your problem with core session instead of building work arounds for your broken work around

Comment: Why did u disable your `core/session`? Its very much required for `Magento`.And you can give a bit more description in your question of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

> Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess("message");

This will work everywhere in frontend.

Comment: This only works, when the message blocks, read the messages from customer/session. So "everywhere" is not quite right. Nonetheless, worth a try! :-)